# Using UpdateView in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I can successfully add a comment with the below code:

views.py:

```
class CommentCreate(CreateView):
    model = Comment
    fields = ['body']

def form_valid(self, form):
    film = Film.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['film_id'])
    form.instance.user = self.request.user
    form.instance.film = film
    return super(CommentCreate, self).form_valid(form)

class CommentUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Comment
    fields = ['body']

def form_valid(self, form):
    film = Film.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['film_id'])
    comment = Film.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['comment_id'])
    form.instance.user = self.request.user
    form.instance.film = film
    form.instance.comment = comment
    return super(CommentUpdate, self).form_valid(form)
```

urls.py:

```
path('<int:film_id>/comment/', views.CommentCreate.as_view(), name='add_comment'),
path('<int:film_id>/comment/', views.CommentUpdate.as_view(), name='update_comment'),
```

models.py:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
# user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    film = models.ForeignKey(Film, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('films:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.film.pk})
```

links in html file:

```
<a href="{% url 'films:add_comment' film_id=film.id %}">Leave a comment</a>

<a href="{% url 'films:update_comment' film_id=film.id %}">Update</a>
```

As you can see, I have tried to add update functionality but at the moment when I click the update link and save a comment it creates a new instance rather than amending an existing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your paths are for create and update are identical. If you don't pass an id for the comment your code won't be able to know which comment it should update (a film may have multiple comments.)
So change your update path to:

```
path('<int:film_id>/comment/<int:comment_id>/', views.CommentUpdate.as_view(), name='update_comment'),
```

and your anchor to

```
<a href="{% url 'films:update_comment' film_id=film.id comment_id=comment.id %}">Update</a>
```

(there's only one create comment button for each film, but for each comment in that film there's a separate update button, so update buttons are bind to comments and should know the comment id.)

Comment: Thank you. This has worked, I think... I get an error but don't think it is because of these changes: Reverse for 'update_comment' with keyword arguments '{'film_id': 2, 'commend_id': 5}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['films/(?P<film_id>[0-9]+)\\/comment\\/(?P<comment_id>[0-9]+)\\/$']

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in my answer that I fixed, `commend` => `comment`.

Comment: That made a difference :). Though i now get... Generic detail view CommentUpdate must be called with either an object pk or a slug. But I thought following the same structure as adding a new comment I would not get this message?

Comment: I use rest framework for my projects and don't have much experience with generic editing views. But I guess replacing `comment_id` with `pk` should work as the error suggests.

Answer (score 1):

you've made the same exact path for update and create and haven't included an identifier in your comment update route.  Django path matches the first one that matches, which is the create route.  You need unique routes.

```
path('<int:film_id>/comment/<int:comment_id>/', views.CommentUpdate.as_view(), name='update_comment'),

<a href="{% url 'films:update_comment' film_id=film.id comment_id=comment.id %}">Update</a>
```

the href might not be defined correctly here because i dont know what your comment structure looks like but you need to pass it the id of the comment you're updating.

Comment: Thank you. This has worked, I think... I get an error but don't think it is because of these changes: Reverse for 'update_comment' with keyword arguments '{'film_id': 2, 'commend_id': 5}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['films/(?P<film_id>[0-9]+)\\/comment\\/(?P<comment_id>[0-9]+)\\/$']